# Manipulate second div with class = row

Tags: html, css

I have the following html code.
Is it possible to manipulate the second row element and how?

```
<style>
.span11 row{}
</style>

<div class="span11">
    <div class="row"></div>
    <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```

It works!

```
.row:nth-child(2){background:#000;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 way:

1. `.row+.row{background:#000;}`
2. `.row:nth-child(2){background:#000;}`

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. Like this.

```
<style>
.span11 .row{
}

.span11 .row + .row {
}
</style>
```

Comment: Is it not nassecary to add all fullstop to row, because it is a class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS3 selector nth-child

Example:

```
.span11 row:nth-child(2)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
```

More info at the [W3 Schools website](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp).

Keep in mind that this solution is future-proof, and will work smoothly in most modern browsers, but will perform poorly on outdated versions of some browsers like Internet Explorer 9 and older.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
.row:nth-child(2) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `nth-child(child number)`
the

```
.row:nth-child(the numbed child here) {

}
```

like in your case you are adjusting for second child so

```
  .row:nth-child(2) {
  // your styles here
  }
```

[Fiddle Link Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PsdDt/)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.span11 div:nth-of-type(3n+2) { border:1px solid red;}`

http://jsfiddle.net/WV3w4/